# How to convert to float

Tags: ida, disassemblers

```
.rdata:00414704 __real@c0800000 dd 0C0800000h
```

How to convert this value 0C0800000h to float point number?

Answer (score 5):

`ALT-D`, then `Float`. (Or `Double`, or `Packed Real`.)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

- Keyboard Shortcut: Alt-D, followed by F
- Action : OpFloat

By the way you can also add keyboard shortcut of your own choice by:

- Menu: Options->Shortcuts
  and then add a shortcut for OpFloat